# Trying to understand notation in real analysis question

Tags: real-analysis, notation

I'm studying real analysis, and I just want to make sure I am understanding the notation of the question correctly:

If $f:\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}, x↦x^2,$ prove that...

So am I correct in saying:

domain: {$x \in \mathbb{R}$}

range: {$y \in \mathbb{R}:y=x^2$}

Thanks.

Comment: I would assume so

Comment: That's peculiar notation. Are you sure it didn't say "If $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$, $x\mapsto x^2$"?

Comment: Yes, it was like that

Comment: The domain and range are sets.  Technically, what you wrote isn't a set, but a statement.  Put braces around what you wrote.

Comment: Then the domain is $\Bbb R$, and the codomain (not range) is $\Bbb R$.

Comment: But is it saying that the function is f(x)=x^2, and you can put any x in the real numbers into that f(x)

Comment: @user11015000 Yes, that is what is being said.

Comment: Okay, thank you

Comment: What is $x$ in $\{y\in\mathbb R: y=x^2\}$?

Answer (score 1):

You are not using set notation properly. Usually, the set notation would be
$$\{ \text{where the elements are taken from} \mid \text{what condition they must satisfy}\}.$$
The condition must be a well-formed formula with no variables that are not explained.

Neither of the ways you write it meets this standard.

If you want to say that the domain all real numbers, you can say “$\mathrm{domain}(f)=\mathbb{R}$”, or you can say the domain is the set $\{x\mid x\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

For the range, you *could* say:
$$\{ y\in\mathbb{R}\mid \text{there exists a real number }x\text{ such that }y=x^2\},$$
but you can’t just write $\{y\in\mathbb{R}\mid y=x^2\}$, because that condition is incomplete: it does not specify what $x$ is or where it is taken from. But in any case, there is a much better way to describe the range of this function that “all real numbers that are equal to the square of a real number”: you can just say they are the nonnegative real numbers.